# Mongodb, Mongoose linking multiple models in different files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've searched around on SO for but can't seem to find the right answer for myself. I'm learning Mongodb using Mongoose and NodeJS, but I have two separate models in separate files ie: users.js and posts.js. 
I am trying to have mongodb query both (because they will be linked) but I don't want to open multiple connections, as I think it would be a waste of resources in production. I have tried it with multiple connections and it works (as per the docs) but there must be a better way to simply require each Schema.
**POSTS**

```
//jshint esversion: 6 
const express    = require(`express`);
const mongoose   = require(`mongoose`);
const bodyParser = require(`body-parser`);
const app = express();

//Initiate body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//initiate posts db
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/postDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

//=== SCHEMAS ===//

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    postTitle: {
        type: String,
        required:[true, `Must enter a title`],
        minlength: [1, `Title must be at least 1 chars`],
        maxlength: [120, `Title cannot be more than 120 chars`]
    },
    postDate: {
        type: Date,
        required:[false]
    },
    postBody: {
        type: String,
        required:[true, `Post must have content`],
        minlength: [1, `Content must be at least 1 chars`],
        maxlength: [50000, `Content cannot be more than 50,000 chars`]
    },
    postAuthor: {
        type: String,
    }
});
```

**Users.js:**

```
const express    = require(`express`);
const mongoose   = require(`mongoose`);
const bodyParser = require(`body-parser`);
const app = express();

//Initiate body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//initiate posts db
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

  //USER SCHEMA//
  {SOME STUFF}
```

**server.js**

```
//jshint esversion: 6 

//=== DEPENDENCIES ===//

//Application global constants
const express    = require(`express`);
const mongoose   = require(`mongoose`);
const bodyParser = require(`body-parser`);
const ejs        = require('ejs');
const _          = require(`lodash`);        
//Initiate Express
const app = express();
module.exports = app;
//Express Routing Requires()
const site = require(`./routes/siteController`);
const user = require(`./routes/userController`);
const post = require(`./routes/postController`);

//=== DEPENDENCY SETTINGS ===//

//Initiate EJS engine
app.set(`view engine`, `ejs`);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
//Initiate body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//Set express static files
app.use(express.static(`public`));
```

Also as I am learning if you have any feedback on the code it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am now in the position to make an answer for my own question. Linking multiple databases to a single connection is very simple with the createConnection() mongoose method, things get slightly more unusual when you have multiple model.js files and a single server.js (or main app.js) file.

My file structure for a visual reference:

```
-MAIN FOLDER
 -controllers
   -userController
   -staticPagesController
   -postsController
 -models
    server.js //I CONTAIN ALL THE DATABASE AND SERVER CONNECTION TOOLS
    posts //I NEED A DB OF MY OWN
    users //I NEED A DB OF MY OWN
 -public
    stylesheets
 -views
    user
      all user ejs files
    post
      all post ejs files
    site
      all staticpage ejs files
    partials
      all partials
 -index.js
```

Inside your server.js file you must create two connections(one for each db) like so:

```
//Create connection one to userDB

const conn1Name = `userDB`;
exports.makeConn1 = mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${conn1Name}`, {useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err){
  if (!err){
    console.log(`Database Server connection created at: ${conn1Name}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Error starting server ${err}`);
  }
});

//Create connection one to postDB
const conn2Name = `postDB`;
exports.makeConn2 = mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${conn2Name}`, {useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err){
  if (!err){
    console.log(`Database Server connection created at: ${conn2Name}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Error starting server ${err}`);
  }
});
```

Each of your model.js files will have its own Schema inside i'll use a User as reference ie:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, `Must Enter A Name`]
    }
)};
```

Inside here you must require your server.js file like so

```
const conn1 = require(`/path/to/server`);
```

**NOW the confusing part that is so very subtle but makes all the difference!**
We set conn1 to require the path to the server so it can connect but we must have a model for our schema to use. We use conn1 to create the model with the following syntax:

```
module.exports = conn1.makeConn1.model(`User`, userSchema);
```

Here we directly export the the now connected model with it's associated schema to wherever we need to require it (ie: your controllers or main app.js). The subtle difference here is that we aren't creating a **new mongoose.model** like the documents suggest, but instead using our newly created connection to call model on.